# Combine multiple queries that each require a row of input values

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

I'm looking for a way to combine multiple queries that each need two values.

For example, I can look up a patient's age and weight as follows:

```sql
select age
     , weight 
  from patients 
  join visits on patientID = patientNum 
 where visits.patientNum = 1;
```

```
+------+--------+
| age  | weight |
+------+--------+
|   15 |   3.64 |
|   41 |      5 |
|  114 |   6.98 |
```

The problem is that I need to perform a query on each row to get their percentile; for example, taking the first row from above:

```sql
select age
     , percentile
     , abs(weight-3.64) as value 
  from Weights 
 where age = 15 
 order by value 
 limit 1;
```

```
+-----+------------+-----------------------+
| age | percentile | val                   |
+-----+------------+-----------------------+
|  15 |         39 | 0.0052000141143797585 |
+-----+------------+-----------------------+
```

The desired output would be:

```
+-----+------------+-----------------------+
| age | percentile | val                   |
+-----+------------+-----------------------+
|  15 |         39 | 0.0052000141143797585 |
|  41 |         83 | 0.0099000930786132810 |
| 114 |         90 | 0.0121998596191410510 |
+-----+------------+-----------------------+
```

I could trivially preform three queries for this example, but I need a way to do this all at once.

Comment: Your schema is unclear. Please edit the question and post the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the tables, some sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has percentiles, as does MariaDB.